# Ionic 4 PWA - Add standard html page in Ionic project

Tags: ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I have an Ionic 4 PWA project and need to add a standard html page which I can access directly via the url.

The problem is when I add the html page in the root (src/app/test.html) or in a folder (src/app/folder/test.html), I cannot access it directly via url - myweb.com/folder/test.html

However, if I put it in my assets folder (src/assets/test.html) I can access it directly via url - myweb.com/assets/test.html

So what do I need to setup so I can access the html in root or specific folder?

Comment: Can you share what example of code from a standard html ?

Comment: `<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>My Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: If I place the html file in the src/assets folder, I can even add AMP page and I can view it using myweb.com/assets/amp,html
Now I want to place the html file in specific folder, not the assets folder so my url would be
myweb.com/amp/amp.html

Answer (score 0):

An Ionic / Angular PWA typically utilises one host file i.e., index.html from which your PWA is loaded. Once your PWA is loaded navigation is handled by [Angular's Router](https://angular.io/guide/router).

By convention static assets are served from the [assets](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#app-source-folder) directory.

Also see: [The Angular Style Guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide)